# How can I copy files to Documents folder of my app through iTunes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I saw some apps like GoodReader have this function.

User can copy their documents to a folder of app through iTunes and then use them in app.

What can I do to perform this function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

UIFileSharingEnabled

UIFileSharingEnabled (Boolean - iOS) specifies whether the application shares files through iTunes. If this key is YES, the application shares files. If it is not present or is NO, the application does not share files. Applications must put any files they want to share with the user in their /Documents directory, where  is the path to the application’s home directory.

In iTunes, the user can access an application’s shared files from the File Sharing section of the Apps tab for the selected device. From this tab, users can add and remove files from the directory.

This key is supported in iOS 3.2 and later.

from: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: This is also the answer to the question, what key can I look for to see what apps allow document-sharing?! - using the library here: https://github.com/programmin1/iosTransferGUI/blob/master/instproxy_browse_installed_app.py

Answer (score 1):

You have to set UIFileSharingEnabled key in the info plist of your app.